# Jasmine testing AngularJS $http

Tags: testing, angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test a REST API wrapped in an AngularJS service using Jasmine async testing. I know, I should be, and am, running tests on the API on the server, and using a mock $httpBackend to test the service, but I'd still like to know how to do async tests where I need to.

The problem I'm having is my deferreds (returned by $http) never seem to resolve. Going past the service and trying to simply use $http has the same problem. What am I doing wrong here:

```
describe('Jasmine + Angular + $http', function() {

    var injector; 

    beforeEach(function() {
        injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    });

    it('can be tested', function() {

        injector.invoke(function($http) {

            var complete = false;

            runs(function() {
                $http.get('...').then(function(res) {
                    complete = true;
                });
            });

            waitsFor(function() {
                return complete;
            }, 'query to complete', 5000);

            runs(function() {
                expect(complete).toEqual(true);
            });

        });

    });

});
```

(I'm using grunt-contrib-jasmine to run the tests)

Comment: I wonder if the global setup of your injector isn't working. Can you try moving it into a beforeEach block, so you'd have `var injector` and then `beforeEach(function(injector = angular.injector(['ng']));`

Comment: I've updated the code building the injector into a beforeEach. The injector seems to be working. I'm getting an $http object that has a get function. The problem seems to be that the deferred it returns is never being resolved.

Comment: If I include jQuery and change the $http to $ (using jQuery's ajax method) everything works perfectly. It definitely seems to be something to do with angular's deferred object handling when injected this way.

Comment: Is there any reason why $http would be null in the case above?

Comment: How did this go for you? Have you checked if it's a CORS issue?

Answer (score 13):

The HTTP requests will not fire unless you call $httpBackend.flush().

More information can be found here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend)